# How can I ensure that an Ansible shell command executes only once per host?

Tags: shell, ansible

I want to be able to guarantee that after a long running shell command is executed successfully on a given host, it is not executed in subsequent playbook runs on that host.

I was happy to learn of the `creates` option to the Ansible shell task (see http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html); using this I can create a file after a shell command succeeds and not have that command execute in future runs:

```
- name: Install Jupiter theme
  shell: wp theme install ~/downloads/jupiter-theme.zip --activate
         && touch ~/ansible-flags/install-jupiter-theme
  args:
    creates: ~/ansible-flags/install-jupiter-theme
```

As you can see, I have a directory `ansible-flags` for these control files in the home directory of my active user (`deploy`).

However, this is quite a kludge.  Is there a better way to do this?

Also, the situation gets a lot more complicated when I need to run a step as a different user; in that case, I don't have access to the `deploy` home directory and its subdirectories.  I could grant access, of course, but that's adding even more complexity. How would you recommend I deal with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ansible itself is stateless, so whatever technique you use needs to be implement by yourself. There is no easier way like telling Ansible to only ever run a task once.

I think what you have already is pretty straight forward. Maybe use another path to check. I'm pretty sure the `wp theme install` will actually extract that zip to some location, which you then can use together with the `creates` option.

There are alternatives but nothing that makes it easier:

- Create a script in any language you like, that checks for the theme and if it is not installed, install it. Instead of the shell task then you would execute the script with the [script module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/script_module.html).
- Install a [local fact](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d) in `/etc/ansible/facts.d` which checks if the theme in already installed. Then you could simply apply a condition based on that fact to the `shell` task.
- Set up [fact caching](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#fact-caching), then register the result of your shell task and store it as a fact. With fact caching enabled you can access the stored result on later playbook runs.

It only gets more complicated. The `creates` option is perfect for this scenario and if you use the location where the `wp` command extracted the zip to, it also is pretty clean.

Of course you need to grant access to that file, if you have a need to access it from another user account. Storing stuff in a users home directory with the permissions set to only be readable by the owner indeed is no ideal solution.

Comment: I provided the example of the WordPress theme, and for some reason I thought the theme would be installed in the data base and not the file system; that's why I created an artificial control file, but you are right, I can look for the theme directory that is created during the theme's installation. (In retrospect, even if it was stored in the DB I should have tried to find a way to query the DB for that piece of information.)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  I see now that, for cases not able to use 'creates', there really is no simpler way to do what I want.

Answer (score 6):

Your playbook should be idempotent!
So either task should be safe to be executed multiple times (e.g. `echo ok`) or your should check whether you should execute it at all.
Your task may look like this:

```
- name: Install Jupiter theme
  shell: wp theme is-installed jupiter || wp theme install ~/downloads/jupiter-theme.zip --activate
```

It will check if the jupiter theme is installed and will run `wp theme install` only if theme is not installed.
But this will mark the result of task as `changed` in any case.
To make it nice, you can do this:

```
- name: Install Jupiter theme
  shell: wp theme is-installed jupiter && echo ThemeAlreadyInstalled || wp theme install ~/downloads/jupiter-theme.zip --activate
  register: cmd_result
  changed_when: cmd_result.stdout != "ThemeAlreadyInstalled"
```

First, it will check if the jupiter theme is already installed.
If this is the case, it will output `ThemeAlreadyInstalled` and exit.
Otherwise it will call `wp theme install`.
The task's result is registered into `cmd_result`.
We user `changed_when` parameter to state the fact that if `ThemeAlreadyInstalled` ansible shouldn't consider the task as changed, so it remains green in your playbook output.

If you do some preparation tasks before `wp theme install` (e.g. download theme), you may want to run the test as separate task to register the result and use `when` clauses in subsequent tasks:

```
- name: Check Jupiter theme is installed
  shell: wp theme is-installed jupiter && echo Present || echo Absent
  register: wp_theme
  changed_when: false

- name: Download theme
  get_url: url=...
  when: wp_theme.stdout == "Absent"

- name: Install Jupiter theme
  shell: wp theme install ~/downloads/jupiter-theme.zip --activate
  when: wp_theme.stdout == "Absent"
```

Comment: I understand the need to be idempotent, but I don't think this question has anything to do with that -- assuming that repeating a step unnecessarily produces the same result as *not* repeating a step unnecessarily, it is idempotent either way, isn't it?

The question here is how to prevent unnecessary task executions in order to save time.

Comment: I've used your suggestion to accurately report whether or not the task was actually performed.  Cool stuff, thanks very much!

Comment: @KeithBennett, to prevent executions you need a test. I bet you actually want not to run command once per host, but to be sure that the theme is installed with every execution of playbook (without installing it if it is already there). Imagine that the flag file is there, but someone deleted the theme manually. In this case you need a test that is true when theme is installed and false otherwise. I think checking it with `wp` command before installing is a good move.

Comment: I agree with you that it is far better to use a test that determines the real status rather than my file kludge which is vulnerable to staleness and error. My question was really for those cases where it is not practical or possible to determine the state definitively; the theme example turned out to be a bad one because, as you point out, there is a much better way.

Comment: There is always some kind of test possible :) When I hit this kind of task I image what would I check manually If I sshed to the host in question.